# How to get Interventation/Image after Resize in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9, intervention

I used Interventation image to resize a big size uploaded image. But I don't want to save it into the local directory of Laravel. This is my sample source code.

```
    public function Uploader(Request $request) {

            $upload_file = $request->file_upload;

            $new_img = Image::make($upload_file)->resize(800, 544);
            $new_img->save(\public_path($fileName));
            $upload_file_new = "../public/" . $fileName;
    }
```

I want to get the new path of the resized image (by not by saving it). I used

```
$path = $new_img->basePath();
```

But it returns the basePath of the `$upload_file`. How can I get the new path so I can use it on `fopen($upload_file_new, 'r')`. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: If you are not _saving_ it anywhere, then how do you expect it to have any "path"?

Comment: @CBroe if I upload an image I get a temp path like this `C:\xampp\tmp/php2F31.tmp` is there a way I can save the resized image like this?

Comment: Use `tempnam`, and use the resulting file name as argument for the `save` method? _Why_ do you think you need something you can open using `fopen`, what is it you actually want to _achieve_ here? Might make more sense to just get the image content into a variable, if you want to do any further work on it? https://image.intervention.io/v2/api/encode

Comment: What do you need the path for? You can handle images without using paths tbh

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
        $image_new_name     = time() . str_random(10) . str_replace(' ','',$upload_file->getClientOriginalName());
```